# Second PhD scholarship while studying a PhD already

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, funding

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

I have a question. Is it illegal if an international student, who is currently studying a PhD with a scholarship in the UK, accept another PhD scholarship from another country simultaneously?

Consider that he is going to continue his PhD in the UK until his visa is granted from the second country, and then he will withdraw from the UK university's scholarship. I do not know if this is illegal or will violate any specific law or regulations. In the scholarship contract is mentioned that student can withdraw any time but should repay a portion of the fee and scholarship.

Will either of these two university know I am doing this? none of them asked me, so I preferred not to say until someone asks me

I really need to know this and would be grateful if someone could give me a right an accurate answer.

Thank you

Comment: One legal question might involve fraud, but probably not otherwise. But there might be reasons beyond strict legality for not doing this without giving notice to everyone.